# tibble add_row not tidy?

Tags: r, row, addition, tibble

Why is this following code not working.
I want add a row to a tibble which I copied from the tibble before.

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tibble)
 tiris <- as_tibble(iris)
 new_row <- tiris %>% tail(1)
 tiris <- tiris %>% add_row(new_row)
```

Error: Column `new_row` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `new_row` you created is a one row `tibble`, so I think what you need is the `bind_rows` function from the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package, which can combine two `tibble` or `data frame` by rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
tiris <- as_tibble(iris)
new_row <- tiris %>% tail(1)
# Combine tiris and new_row
tiris <- tiris %>% bind_rows(new_row)
```

See the last two rows of `tiris`, which are identical. So I think `bind_rows` works.

```
# View the results
tail(tiris, 2)
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  
#          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>    
# 1         5.90        3.00         5.10        1.80 virginica
# 2         5.90        3.00         5.10        1.80 virginica
```